# A special case of Lob's theorem using Coq

Tags: coq, lob, coq-tactic

I have a formula inductively defined as follows:

```
Parameter world : Type.
Parameter R : world -> world -> Prop.
Definition Proposition : Type := world -> Prop

(* This says that R has only a finite number of steps it can take *)
Inductive R_ends : world -> Prop :=
 | re : forall w, (forall w', R w w' -> R_ends w') -> R_ends w.
 (*  if every reachable state will end then this state will end *)
```

And hypothesis:

```
Hypothesis W : forall w, R_ends w.
```

I would like to prove:

```
forall P: Proposition, (forall w, (forall w0, R w w0 -> P w0) -> P w)) -> (forall w, P w)
```

I tried using the `induction` tactic on the type `world` but failed since it is not an inductive type.

Is it provable in Coq and if yes, can you suggest how?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use structural induction on a term of type `R_ends`:

```
Lemma lob (P : Proposition) (W : forall w, R_ends w) :
    (forall w, (forall w0, R w w0 -> P w0) -> P w) -> (forall w, P w).
Proof.
  intros H w.
  specialize (W w).
  induction W.
  apply H.
  intros w' Hr.
  apply H1.
  assumption.
Qed.
```

Incidentally, you could have defined `R_ends` in a slightly different manner, using a parameter instead of an index:

```
Inductive R_ends (w : world) : Prop :=
 | re : (forall w', R w w' -> R_ends w') -> R_ends w.
```

When written this way, it's easy to see that `R_ends` is analogous to the accessibility predicate `Acc`, defined in the standard library ([`Coq.Init.Wf`](https://coq.inria.fr/library/Coq.Init.Wf.html#Acc)):

```
Inductive Acc (x: A) : Prop :=
     Acc_intro : (forall y:A, R y x -> Acc y) -> Acc x.
```

It's used to work with well-founded induction.